# Tabular: l{unit}?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I would like to define a few table columns with fixed width, just like p{2cm}, but I prefer the text to be flushed left, instead of justified. So basically something like l{2cm}.

Is there a way to achieve that without having to touch every cell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}% with hyphenation
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}% without hyphenation
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{L{5cm}M{5cm}}
\blindtext & \blindtext
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: remember `\arraybackslash` or ` \\ ` will not work (can someone please markup \\?

Comment: right, I edited the answer

Comment: I would do it in both, then the order does not matter for the user

Comment: @daleif: it is one of the nice features of `ragged2e` that `\RaggedRight` does it for me ... ;-)